# reading objects from binary data

Tags: c++, binary

I have been reading an array of SRD objects from a binary file - but since this was my first time doing so, I have modified a header making all its members public as I wasn't sure what would be going on. I have completed my assignment, all that is left is to make these members private and write methods that modify them. However, there is a problem.
For debugging purposes I put only 1 member private, and until I write all methods for it I will keep it that way. This member is simply an unsigned int C. When writing a method for returning it (getC() returns C), it is returning a value of 0000...3435973836, meaning it is not set? 
So, I have an array of pointers to SRD created based on the number of objects in the binary file.

```
SRD *a;
...
a = new SRD[numOfRecords];
```

and the array is filled from the file...

```
for (i=0; i<numOfRecords; i++)
    {
        f.seekg(i * sizeof s);  
        f.read((char *)&a[i], sizeof s);
        cout << a[i].getCC();
    }
```

now, `a[i].getCC()` works when C is public, but making it private makes 000..3435...
meaning accessing it is not the problem, but it is not set in the fread from the previous for loop. I imagine I need some type of assignment operator, that sets these values, but I have no clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was something else: the header was defined in a certain order, the first member was an array, while C was the second, and while debugging i first started with the C - and moving it from the second position to the above public one, changed the structure of the class.

so,

```
Class P
{
int i;
char c;
}
```

differs from

```
Class P
{
char c;
int i;
}
```

because the data in the binary file has a specific order, and when rearranging the order of the class defenition, a member (c) tries to access data intended for another member (i)

Answer (score 1):

When you make the variable private, the SRD class is no longer [plain old data (POD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure). Consequently, you have no guarantees regarding its in-memory representation, and therefore you cannot rely on `f.read` to work like this any longer.

I suggest that you add a read-from-stream method in your class and inside that method, `read` directly to the unsigned int member variable. Then, in the loop, you just call that method (passing the stream as a reference or a pointer).

**EDIT**, example as requested:

```
class SRD {
  ...
  public:
    void readFromStream(istream& f) {
      f.read(&CC, sizeof CC);
    }
  private:
    unsigned int CC;
};
```

Loop:

```
for (i=0; i<numOfRecords; i++)
{
    a[i].readFromStream(f);
    cout << a[i].getCC();
}
```

Comment: can you write a simple example, say simply a 1 member class on how to do this?

Comment: Example added, hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, the problem was something else: the header was defined in a certain order, the first member was an array, while C was the second, and while debugging i first started with the C - and moving it from the second position to the above public one, changed the structure of the class.

so,

    Class P
    {
    int i;
    char c;
    }

differs from

    Class P
    {
    char c;
    int i;
    }

because the data in the binary file has a specific order, and when rearranging the order of the class defenition, a member (c) tries to access data intended for another member (i)